# Change Visual Studio 2008 HTML indentation style

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, indentation

Visual Studio 2008 insists on indenting HTML like this:

```
<h1>
    title</h1>
<h2>
    subtitle</h2>
```

where for me, this is much nicer:

```
<h1>title</h1>
<h2>subtitle</h2>
```

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio 2008 to use the later indentation style when doing auto-formating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Options, under HTML, go to "Format" and click "Tag Specific Options". Then find the tags you want to change (h1, h2, etc.) and uncheck indent contents. ([Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/07/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Custom-formatting-HTML-in-Visual-Web-Developer-and-Visual-Studio-2005.aspx))

The guide linked above is for Visual Studio 2005, so it may be slightly different for 2008, but I'm sure you'll find it.